# iTextSharp Table Span Pages using Stamper

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have a template PDF that contains form data that is a constant height. Under that data, I need to add a table that has a dynamic height. This table may only be one line, and one row, or it may contain 1000 lines and/or 1-1000 rows.

This is the Code that I have that works fine, except, the table will not span to a new page if it is to large.

```
private void InsertCurrentNeightborsOlder(string FileName)
{
//Create new PDF document 
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 20f, 20f, 0f, 20f);
iTextSharp.text.Font fntTableFontHdr = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
iTextSharp.text.Font fntTableFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);


try {
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create));
    PdfPTable nTbl = new PdfPTable(5);

    // Build the header
    PdfPCell CellOneHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", fntTableFontHdr));
    nTbl.AddCell(CellOneHdr);
    PdfPCell CellTwoHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address", fntTableFontHdr));
    CellTwoHdr.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    nTbl.AddCell(CellTwoHdr);
    PdfPCell CellTreeHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Phone #", fntTableFontHdr));
    CellTreeHdr.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    nTbl.AddCell(CellTreeHdr);
    PdfPCell CellFouHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Method", fntTableFontHdr));
    CellFouHdr.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    nTbl.AddCell(CellFouHdr);
    PdfPCell CellFivHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Comments", fntTableFontHdr));
    nTbl.AddCell(CellFivHdr);


    //create column sizes 
    float[] rows = {
        100f,
        100f,
        70f,
        100f,
        100f
    };
    //set row width 
    nTbl.SetTotalWidth(rows);

    nTbl.CompleteRow();

    // Add the Cells to the data table
    if (ReportDataSet.Tables("CurrentNeighbors").Rows.Count > 0) {
        foreach (DataRow r in ReportDataSet.Tables("CurrentNeighbors").Rows) {
            nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph(r("FullName").ToString, fntTableFont));
            nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph(r("Address").ToString, fntTableFont));

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(r("PhoneNumber").ToString, fntTableFont));
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            nTbl.AddCell(cell);


            // nTbl.AddCell(New Paragraph(r("PhoneNumber").ToString, fntTableFont))
            nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph(r("ContactMethod").ToString, fntTableFont));
            nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph(r("Comments").ToString, fntTableFont));
        }
    } else {
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("Nothing Entered", fntTableFont));
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("              ", fntTableFont));
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("              ", fntTableFont));
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("              ", fntTableFont));
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("              ", fntTableFont));
    }
    document.Open();

    nTbl.HeaderRows = 1;
    nTbl.SplitLate = false;
    document.Add(nTbl);

} catch (Exception ex) {
} finally {
    document.Close();
}
```

}

The "FileName" Parameter passed contains the location of the original file that I want to add the table to.

Is it even possible to do, and if so, what am I missing?

EDIT:

Here is another function that I tried (Using the Stamper). I may be way off on this one too, but that is what I am attempting to find out:

```
private void InsertCurrentNeightbors(string FileName)
{
// This is the Temporary File that we are working with. This file already has data in it
string oldFile = FileName;
// Create a new Temporary file that we can write to
string newFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetTempFileName();
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = null;
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper = null;
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = null;
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = null;
int pageCount = 0;

try {
    reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(oldFile);
    rect = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
    stamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, new System.IO.FileStream(newFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
    iTextSharp.text.Font fntTableFontHdr = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
    iTextSharp.text.Font fntTableFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

    cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
    dynamic ct = new ColumnText(cb);
    ct.Canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(reader.NumberOfPages + 1);
    ct.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(70, 36, PageSize.A4.Width - 36, PageSize.A4.Height - 300);
    PdfPTable nTbl = new PdfPTable(5);

    // Build the header
    PdfPCell CellOneHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", fntTableFontHdr));
    nTbl.AddCell(CellOneHdr);
    PdfPCell CellTwoHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address", fntTableFontHdr));
    CellTwoHdr.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    nTbl.AddCell(CellTwoHdr);
    PdfPCell CellTreeHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Phone #", fntTableFontHdr));
    CellTreeHdr.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    nTbl.AddCell(CellTreeHdr);
    PdfPCell CellFouHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Method", fntTableFontHdr));
    CellFouHdr.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    nTbl.AddCell(CellFouHdr);
    PdfPCell CellFivHdr = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Comments", fntTableFontHdr));
    nTbl.AddCell(CellFivHdr);


    //create column sizes 
    float[] rows = {
        100f,
        100f,
        70f,
        100f,
        100f
    };
    //set row width 
    nTbl.SetTotalWidth(rows);

    nTbl.CompleteRow();

    // Add the Cells to the data table
    if (ReportDataSet.Tables("CurrentNeighbors").Rows.Count > 0) {
        foreach (DataRow r in ReportDataSet.Tables("CurrentNeighbors").Rows) {
            nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph(r("FullName").ToString, fntTableFont));
            nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph(r("Address").ToString, fntTableFont));
            nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph(r("PhoneNumber").ToString, fntTableFont));
            nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph(r("ContactMethod").ToString, fntTableFont));
            nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph(r("Comments").ToString, fntTableFont));
        }
    } else {
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("Nothing Entered", fntTableFont));
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("              ", fntTableFont));
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("              ", fntTableFont));
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("              ", fntTableFont));
        nTbl.AddCell(new Paragraph("              ", fntTableFont));
    }



    nTbl.SplitLate() = false;
    nTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, 25, 85, 490, stamper.GetOverContent(reader.NumberOfPages));

    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();
    ct.Go();

    // Now that the new temp file has been written, we need to delete the old temp file
    // and rename the new temp file to the old temp file name

    // Delete Old Temp file
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(FileName);

    // Rename the new temp file to the old temp file

    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(newFile, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName));

} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}

}
```

I did try the link that you provided, but it did not work as expected. All “I” was able to do is repeat the source page 100 times onto the destination page. I know that it was all to do with my interpretation of the source code, and the conversion, but this is what I got:

```
private void manipulatePdf(string src, string dest)
{
try {
    // Read the template file into the reader variable
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    // Get the page side of the template file
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pagesize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

    // Create a Stamper for the destination file
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new System.IO.FileStream(dest, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

    // Create a new Paragraph
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    // Add Text into the new paragraph
    p.Add(new Chunk("Hello "));
    p.Add(new Chunk("World"));

    // Declare your AcroFields so we can get the last field's position
    AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields();
    // Get the Last AcroField's Position
    Rectangle rect = form.GetFieldPositions("MethodOfVerification")(0).position;

    int status = 0;
    PdfImportedPage newPage = null;
    ColumnText column = new ColumnText(stamper.GetOverContent(1));
    column.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
    int pagecount = 1;

    // Add's 100 Items
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        i += 1;
        // Creates a new paragraph object
        column.AddElement(new Paragraph("Hello " + i.ToString));

        // Adds the paragraph object to the column
        column.AddElement(p);
        // Draw content of column
        status = column.Go();
        if (ColumnText.HasMoreText(status)) {
            // Creates a new page and stamps the Source PDF into the Destination PDF
            newPage = loadPage(newPage, reader, stamper);
            triggerNewPage(stamper, pagesize, newPage, column, rect, System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(pagecount));
        }
    }
    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
}

}

public PdfImportedPage loadPage(PdfImportedPage page, PdfReader reader, PdfStamper stamper)
{
if (page == null) {
    return stamper.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
}
return page;
}

public void triggerNewPage(PdfStamper stamper, Rectangle pagesize, PdfImportedPage page, ColumnText column, Rectangle rect, int pagecount)
{
stamper.InsertPage(pagecount, pagesize);
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(pagecount);
canvas.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
//  column.setCanvas(canvas)
column.Canvas() = canvas;
column.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
column.Go();
}
```

Comment: Can you start the dynamic rendering on  new page or does it have to pick up immediately where the other left off?

Comment: I want it to render where the last text left off. The reason being, the two are related. I know that the easy answer would be to dynamically generate the fist part of the form, but I am hoping for a more elegant way to do this. My ultimate goal is to generate a PDF that is going to average 50 pages long.

Comment: One solution you could try if you could start a new page would be too create a new pdf with data gathered from reading the other, then merge the two documents.

Comment: That is what I am doing now. After this function exits, it merges all of the documents together as one. The problem is that when they are merged, it cuts off the rows/lines that extend past the end of the page.

Comment: So I understand, if your first document is 2 pages and then your add another document that is 50+ pages the result is only 3?

Comment: @Talsiter *"The problem is that when they are merged, it cuts off the rows/lines that extend past the end of the page."* - maybe you should post *that* code because that code seems to have the issue, doesn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to continue field output on a second page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-continue-field-output-second-page) Your code is in contradiction with your question. Your question is about adding a table to an existing PDF (as explained in the duplicate question). You may be making the assumption that PDF is like a Word processing format and that content automatically reflows if you add extra content in-between existing content. Obviously that assumption is wrong: you're dealing with PDF where all content has fixed coordinates on a page.

Comment: You also say *The "FileName" Parameter passed contains the location of the original file that I want to add the table to* but that doesn't make sense, does it? When you create a `PdfWriter` instance, you write *a new file* and in your code `FileName` is the place where you want to write the new file that is created from scratch. In the title of your question, you mention `stamper` which means you've probably heard about the `PdfStamper` class, a class that accepts a `PdfReader` instance that will read the existing template so that `PdfStamper` can add content.

Comment: You ask: *what am I missing?* The answer to that question is simple: you forgot to read the [official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/). For instance: you should also read [How to add a table on a form (and maybe insert a new page)?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-table-form-and-maybe-insert-new-page)

Comment: Bruno, I have been working on and off on this for about three weeks. I have been stumped at every corner. I have read all the documentation that I could find, I purchased iText in Action (to provide a little support to you for ALL your efforts in the development and looking for an answer), even though I don’t know Java.  I have read countless numbers of your posts (and flames) attempting to see if this can be done. As far as reading the Official documentation, I have read it, but the problem is my comprehension of it.

Comment: You did a GREAT job on this library, I know that you are proud of it. It amazes me at what it can do, and it is hard for me to believe that what I am wanting it to do, can’t be done. For me, I think that it is more realistic that I am not asking the question the correct way. In reality, all I want to do is, using and existing PDF, create a table that is a dynamic height and attach it to a particular location on that PDF. If the height of the table spans to additional pages, it will re-write the headers on the subsequent pages and continue until the end of the table.

Comment: lrb,
Basically, after it is all said and done, I will have created several Temporary PDF’s, similar to chapters in a book. In reality these temporary files are sections of the final document to be saved. While this section may only be 1 to x number of pages (depending on the information that was entered by the user), the complete document has 32 other sections, and this is only one of those 32 sections. Once all of the sections are built, I will merge them together to make 1 document resulting in one large document.

Comment: Is it possible to share your PDF?

Comment: @Talsiter The problem with your question is that it goes all places. This is simple: *All “I” was able to do is repeat the source page 100 times onto the destination page.* The single source page is called [stationery](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/stationery) and that's explained in the book. See the [Stationery](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6#268-stationery.java) example. What you write in your comment about creating different snippets of PDF and then stitching them together hoping the result will relfow nicely, is impossible.

Comment: Depending on what it is you want to do, it could be a piece of cake, or it could be impossible. Unfortunately, you're describing your problem in a way that confuses people.

Comment: Let's examine your question: *I have a template PDF that contains form data that is a constant height.* Is your template PDF an interactive form and is the data filled out in AcroForm fields? *Under that data, I need to add a table that has a dynamic height.* Is there an AcroForm field that marks where you want to add the table with a height that may vary based on the number of rows that will be added?

Comment: *This is the Code that I have that works fine, except, the table will not span to a new page if it is to large.*  If you use *document.Add()* to add a table, the table is split and a new page is created automatically of the table is too large. *The "FileName" Parameter passed contains the location of the original file that I want to add the table to.* You can't write to the "original file", yet this is what you're trying to do. This can't be correct. Your code doesn't correspond with your question.

Comment: Amedee, here are the files. "Current Address.pdf" is my template file, that I want to add the table to. "TablePDF.pdf" is what I am attempting to merge into "Current Address.pdf". "ProblemPDF_NEW.pdf" is what I am getting, as you can see, it cuts off the remaining lines (using the stamper).    It makes sense to me, that if you use the stamper, it will only display until the end of the page, I am just not sure what function to use... Bruno, I will come back to this...

Comment: In your first `PdfStamper` example, you define a `rect` that you never use. You also define a `ct` to which you never add content. You just add 25 rows of the table at an absolute position and you claim *it did not work as expected.* It is hard to tell what you expected. It is hard to tell why you introduce `rect` and `ct` and then never use those objects.

Comment: @Talsiter You say *As you can see, it cuts off the remaining lines (using the stamper).* Where exactly can we see this? Also: `PdfStamper` is what you use if you have a single PDF. How would you be merging "TablePDF.pdf" into "Current Address.pdf" using `PdfStamper`? That doesn't really make sense. Where does "TablePDF.pdf" come from? Is it a PDF you've created from scratch? Why don't you clean up your question to make it less confusing?

Comment: Bruno, thank you for your reply, briefly looking over "Importing Company Stationary" in the book looks promising. I will look at the example code in the link.

Comment: Bruno, I am looking for resources and code everywhere, I am not sure if the code I am looking at is correct or incorrect, but obviously it is incorrect because it is not working... If you look at "ProblemPDF_NEW.pdf", the last line is "delicata salutandi, in illum" however, I am trying to find out how to continue that table to the next page. What my intensions are is to some how place the table (dynamically created from data in a database) that is found in "TablePDF.pdf" under "10. Current Neighbors Contacted:" FYI, I am still looking at the "Stationary Examples" Thanks again!

Comment: @Talsiter You refer to `ProblemPDF_NEW.pdf` but I have no idea where to find that file. Also: you are assuming that the text "delicata salutandi, in illum" is easy to find in a PDF. If you'd know how PDF works, you'd know that this isn't trivial. You are ignoring my previous questions, such as: do you have interactive form fields in your PDF? Those form fields mark the coordinates you need. If there are none, your assignment is too complex to answer on SO.

Comment: @Talsiter In case you are frustrated: please understand that you're frustrating your audience too by referring to PDFs that nobody but you can see. Why do you ask us to look `TablePDF.pdf` and other files *if you don't even bother to share those documents?* Also, you should tag people when addressing them. If you don't tag people, they don't know you're asking them a question. In any case: I'm leaving for SXSW in Texas later this week (Obama will be there too) and I won't be following this discussion for a couple of weeks.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, I am not getting frustrated, it is a challenge. I know it can be done, I just need to figure out what I am doing wrong. I know it is something simple. I thought I linked to the Files, but looking back I didn't. I am not trying to frustrate people that are here to help. Enjoy your the festival and when you get back please follow this and I hoped to have figured it out by then

Comment: Sorry about the files that I thought I shared, here is the link to them on Drop Canvas http://dropcanvas.com/3h4jv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this helps but I've ported and slightly modified [Bruno sample code](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-table-form-and-maybe-insert-new-page) to a C# version. The first block (`file_1`) creates a sample file and stores the last known coordinate so that we can resume with a table later. The second block (`file_2`) then uses a `PdfStamper` and a `ColumnText` to start the table and continuously adds pages until the table fits. The code itself, especially the second block, has comments that better explain things.

You should be able to re-work the first block to your form's logic to get the coordinates (it seems like you've got that part down) and then just use the second block with your local table.

```
//Working folder
var exportFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "SO_17589177");
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(exportFolder);

//File 1 is our "template" file, File 2 is our final file
var file_1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(exportFolder, "file_1.pdf");
var file_2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(exportFolder, "file_2.pdf");

//Will hold a rectangle based on the last known coordinates
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle tableRectStart;

using (var fs = new FileStream(file_1, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
            doc.Open();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello world"));
            }

            //Store our coordinates for later
            tableRectStart = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(doc.Left, doc.Bottom, doc.Right, writer.GetVerticalPosition(false));

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}

using (var r = new PdfReader(file_1)) {
    using (var fs = new FileStream(file_2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
        using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(r, fs)) {

            //We want to target the last page of the previous PDF
            int pageNumber = r.NumberOfPages;

            //Store the last page's size which is what we'll use for new pages later
            var docRect = r.GetPageSize(pageNumber);

            //Create a giant table
            var t = new PdfPTable(2);
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                t.AddCell(String.Format("This is cell {0}", i));
            }

            //Create our stamper bound to the last page of our source document
            var ct = new ColumnText(stamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber));

            //Add our table to the stamper
            ct.AddElement(t);

            //Set the drawing area for the table
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(tableRectStart);

            //Infinite loop below that is responsible for breaking itself out
            //Might want to add guards in case content gets too big and always overflows
            while (true) {

                //Draw the text and pass the status back to a helper
                //method that tells us if there's more text to be drawn
                if (! ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go())) {
                    //If there isn't any more text then exit the infinite loop
                    break;
                }

                //Reset our rectangle to the document's rectangle
                tableRectStart = docRect;

                //Increment the current page number (which we need to keep track of)
                //and insert a new page
                stamper.InsertPage(++pageNumber, docRect);

                //Tell the ColumnText to draw on a new page
                ct.Canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber);

                //Reset the drawing canvas area
                //TODO: Include some margin logic here probably
                ct.SetSimpleColumn(docRect);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked, thank you so much. I am not sure that I would have been able to figure that out. Thanks again.